# WIF Session token/cookie and load balancer / server farm

Tags: load-balancing, session-cookies, wif

After authentication, client browser uses SessionSecurityToken (serialized stored in cookie) to talk with server, web server (WIF) use session ID and keygen to find SessionSecurityToken object. 
I have a question, if load balancer redirects user to another web server, how WIF will handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two ways : either you configure your servers to use "sticky sessions" (same request always to the same server) or you share the machine key between the servers in your farm.  It's all explained in this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545457(v=vs.110).aspx